# PATH OSX Eclipse Luna Spark Scala Play Framework 2

Tags: eclipse, macos, path, playframework-2.0, apache-spark

BEGINNER QUESTION: I do not have extensive shell (or other) experience.

My objective is to build Spark applications using Eclipse.  I installed Luna, and Scala, and successfully ran:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
println("Scala Rocks!")
}
```

Now I want to install and run Spark applications within Play Framework per these instructions: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Installing

But, I probably do not have the PATH correct.

```
Myname-MacBook-Pro:~ myname$ echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/myname/Documents/Spark/Activator

Myname-MacBook-Pro:~ myname$ activator -help
-bash: activator: command not found
```

THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Your title isn't a question. Please read the FAQ and rewrite your question with it in mind.

Comment: To clarify, you should have your tags in the `tags` section, and the title should be a one-sentence version of your question. For that matter, you should probably put your question in the body as well -- what are you asking for help with? All I see is what you've done so far and what you think the problem is. Both are great things to include, but without a question, no one can answer.

Comment: Have you installed activator, as explained in the link you provide? If yes, have you installed it in the path you've added to the PATH, i.e. /Users/myname/Documents/Spark/Activator? If yes, what do you see when you run 'ls -al /Users/myname/Documents/Spark/Activator'? Anyhow, please take into account @newbiedoolde's comment.

Comment: See next comment please

Comment: Yes, running 'ls -al/Users/myname/Documents/Spark/Activator' shows a list of the files in that directory, but then ...
MyName-MacBook-Pro:~ myname$ activator -help
-bash: activator: command not found

Answer (score 1):

I met the similar issue when using Activator for Play framework 2.3.7. My final solution is adding these lines in my `.zshrc` file (you can change to `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` or `.profile` if you are using Bash):

```
alias activator=~/.activator/activator
```

Hopefully helps. But anyway you should edit your title to summarize you problem in one sentence. Also you could update your problem by editing your problem description.